# When someone crosses your arm or leaves a mark on your arm

Tags: verbs

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D23Nj.jpg)

Imagine a child is playing with his older brother; the child has a pen at hand and suddely he **crosses his brother's arm** OR **marks his brother's arm**

I would appreciate it if you let me know which one of the above-mentioned bold sentences sounds more natural based on my description and the respective uploded image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He draws on his brothers arm.

We cross the road. "To cross" does not mean to mark with a pen.  It would be possible to say "He marked his brothers arm", but without context I would understand that to mean "He made a scratch, bitemark or similar".  "He marked ... with a pen" is also possible.

However the verb "draw" doesn't always imply art, saying "he drew on..." would seem to be the simplest way of saying this.